# Cant close position before opening new

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

When i have my Long position, and condition for Short is met, i wanna close long and go in Short.
But its only opening new position, but not closing, am i doing something wrong?

```
if condition == 1 and strategy.position_size < 0
    strategy.close("Short_close", "Short")
if condition == 1 and strategy.position_size == 0
    strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long)
if condition == -1 and strategy.position_size > 0
    strategy.close("Long_close", "Long")
if condition == -1 and strategy.position_size == 0
    strategy.entry("Short", strategy.short)
```

Also when i added `strategy.position_size == 0` to entrys, it stopped working, don't understand why.

Answer (score 0):

Hedging is not allowed on Tradingview. So, going the other direction will automatically close the previous order.

If you want to do this anyway, avoid the extra checks and use the correct `id`. The first parameter of the `strategy.close()` is `id`. You need to specify which order you want to close. In your example, it should either be `Long` or `Short`.

```
if condition == 1
    strategy.close("Short")
    strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long)
if condition == -1
    strategy.close("Long")
    strategy.entry("Short", strategy.short)
```

`strategy.position_size == 0` will only work if you are not in a position. You don't need this check.